# How would you find the Merkle Root with a Block that contains 6 transactions?

Tags: hash, sha256, merkle-tree

Let's use block #100205
https://www.blockchain.com/en/btc/block/0000000000033d0de6f4ebe93b3b142424cdbecf4bd98b948e856c4a55f09f76

This block contains 6 transactions. After the second level of hashing you end up with 3 nodes. What is the fix for this? Do you create two 5's and 6's?

Answer (score 3):

You would duplicate the hash of the last two txs. The tree would "look" something like this:

```
             abcdefef
              /  \            
           /        \          
        /              \       
      abcd             efef     
      /  \            /  \    
   /        \      /        \  
  ab        cd    ef        ef 
 / \        / \   / \  
a   b      c  d  e   f
```

Answer (score 0):

TXID 1
438edc1b0d7ad70f289bb9c082681aa50ee1c3d63dbf106b092abe224f0636a7
Byteswapped: a736064f22be2a096b10bf3dd6c3e10ea51a6882c0b99b280fd77a0d1bdc8e43

TXID 2
B91aad22dcfe4fca4b03143682642994c607a832d1c4c11c5fd6616310468f8b
Byteswapped: 8b8f46106361d65f1cc1c4d132a807c6942964823614034bca4ffedc22ad1aB9

Hash12 = 
601bffd3fa633bc7cc0ede9f486a5bef88dc8781a58ee4e8c0dd15401000cb71

TXID 3
Daadc472b760fb0586ed2841a9160e99175f05813ce51455f3c08c9765a2a60e
Byteswapped: 0ea6a265978cc0f35514e53c81055f17990e16a94128ed8605fb60b772c4adDa

TXID 4
6543b2025fea04eac45b81304ace9a7672b7a0969a8e9460e4f5cc93062414ce
Byteswapped: ce14240693ccf5e460948e9a96a0b772769ace4a30815bc4ea04ea5f02b24365

Hash34 = 
6c06a7a9e71f66ad01ccf6606176005cad6f5a1a897041f7f8b38a46e62a253a

Hash1234 = 
D4ff4562b9a0fcd529e9dc80b4466a3a78d6cb03909f8303ae5f38774ed7db2d

TXID 5
E4cb63ed4d06c90be633985f2d6902833c4b502d77fdcb883d5217dfaa75dcc5
Byteswapped: c5dc75aadf17523d88cbfd772d504b3c8302692d5f9833e60bc9064ded63cbE4

TXID 6
B64212bc2fc6e1b469d31bc9140d7164794615b257c51f02d067f2a42aad943d
Byteswapped: 3d94ad2aa4f267d0021fc557b215467964710d14c91bd369b4e1c62fbc1242B6

Hash 56 = 
49622b3e9ab2aaa1fdd94b56d9f88d9a5604eb5b053781a7668f3056a92e272c

Hash 56 = 
49622b3e9ab2aaa1fdd94b56d9f88d9a5604eb5b053781a7668f3056a92e272c

Hash5656 =
2d8a2fb663d0d018f5343321598d3647b342b06a52306b0e8392bf8273d746a7

Hash12345656=
af72e3305e599e39381b45dd328abf2cf740280ca8328fa15fc76820e9bdc5ca
Byteswapped: **cac5bde92068c75fa18f32a80c2840f72cbf8a32dd451b38399e595e30e372af**

Worked Like A Charm - Thank You @Raghav Sood